# Separar una url con Javascript y guardarla en una variable

Tags: javascript

Quisiera poder guardar la url en una variable, la url viene de esta manera

```
https://www.midominio.com/sites/document/indice1.txt
```

solo necesito `https://www.midominio.com/sites/document/`

gracias.

Comment: recuerda aceptar la respuesta que mejor se adapte a tu pregunta, así ayudarás a mentener la salud del sitio por % de respuestas resueltas. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas repasar la **Biblia de JavaScript, [`String.prototype.substring()` (*Mozilla*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring)**:

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var cadenaDeTexto = "https://www.midominio.com/sites/document/indice1.txt";
var ultimoSlash = cadenaDeTexto.lastIndexOf("/"); 
console.log(ultimoSlash);
console.log(cadenaDeTexto.substring(0, ultimoSlash+1));

var hastaSites = cadenaDeTexto.indexOf('/document');
console.log(hastaSites);
console.log(cadenaDeTexto.substring(0, hastaSites+1));
```

Comment: y como puedo sacar hasta https://www.midominio.com/sites/

Comment: listo hermanita :D

Answer (score 0):

Podría usar [Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) para reemplazar  en el array (lo que retorna [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split)) aplicando el  metodo [Pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop) que simula un `Desapilar` (Eliminar el ultimo elemento apilado en este caso indice1.txt) (Pila)
Para más información sobre estos métodos ir a la documentación (Lo  Primero)
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array

```
    var str = "https://www.midominio.com/sites/document/indice1.txt";
    var result = str.replace(str.split('/').pop(),'');
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa una expresión regular como la siguiente:

```
/(^.+\/).+\..{3}$/
```

- `()` grupo de captura
- `^` inicio de la expresión
- `.` cualquier caracter
- `+` Al menos uno o más cacteres
- `\/` La diagonal es una caracter especial por lo que hay que escaparlo
- `\.` El punto es una caracter especial por lo que hay que escaparlo
- `{3}` Tres caracteres iguales al predecesor
- `$` fin de la expresión

Ejemplo:

```js
var URL = "https://www.midominio.com/sites/document/indice1.txt";
var re =/(^.+\/).+\..{3}$/
var resultado = re.exec(URL);
console.log(resultado[1]);
```